# How do I parse an html file without using Jsoup?

Tags: java, html

I need to parse through and HTML file for a homework project, and therefore I can't use Jsoup.

I have tried crawling through the file, but I don't know how to save what I'm looking for.

This is what I have:

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(fis);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inStream);

    String fileLine;
    while((fileLine = reader.readLine()) != null){

        String tag = fileLine.substring(fileLine.indexOf("<") + 1,fileLine.indexOf(">"))
    }
```

I need to find the information inside the title> tags, but I can't figure out how to get that information without getting tags I don't need or how to handle cases where there are no tags.

I want to take the information in the title tag and turn it into a string that I can use.

Comment: How is the actual html file? And how is it formatted? Do you need to read it line by line? Posting the actual html file might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String fileDataString = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), Charset.forName("UTF-8")).stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

String title = StringUtils.substringBetween(fileDataString, "<title>", "</title>"));
```

This should work to get the text between < title > and < /title >

EDIT: Thank you BlackPearl for the `Stream<String>.collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));` suggestion

Comment: This approach will work only if the opening and closing title tags are on the same line.

Comment: Changed it so it first reads the whole file. then looks for the title tags and gets the string in between

Comment: or better, `stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))`

Comment: still not pure Java. `StringUtils` belong to _Apache Commons_